# Squeryl session management with 'using'

Tags: scala, squeryl

I'm learning Squeryl and trying to understand the 'using' syntax but can't find documentation on it.

In the following example two databases are created, A contains the word **Hello**, and B contains **Goodbye**.  The intention is to query the contents of A, then append the word **World** and write the result to B.

Expected console output is **Inserted Message(2,HelloWorld)**

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        import Library._

        val sessionA = Session.create(DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:h2:file:data/dbA","sa","password"),new H2Adapter)
        val sessionB = Session.create(DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:h2:file:data/dbB","sa","password"),new H2Adapter)

        using(sessionA){
            drop; create
            myTable.insert(Message(0,"Hello"))
        }
        using(sessionB){
            drop; create
            myTable.insert(Message(0,"Goodbye"))
        }

        using(sessionA){
            val results = from(myTable)(s => select(s))//.toList

            using(sessionB){
                results.foreach(m => {
                    val newMsg = m.copy(msg = (m.msg+"World"))
                    myTable.insert(newMsg)
                    println("Inserted "+newMsg)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    case class Message(val id: Long, val msg: String) extends KeyedEntity[Long]
    object Library extends Schema { val myTable = table[Message] }
}
```

As it stands, the code prints **Inserted Message(2,GoodbyeWorld)**, unless the **toList** is added on the end of the **val results** line.

Is there some way to bind the **results** query to use **sessionA** even when evaluated inside the **using(sessionB)**?  This seems preferable to using **toList** to force the query to evaluate and store the contents in memory.

**Update**

Thanks to Dave Whittaker's answer, the following snippet fixes it without resorting to 'toList' and corrects my understanding of both 'using' and the running of queries.

```
val results = from(myTable)(s => select(s))

using(sessionA){            
    results.foreach(m => {
        val newMsg = m.copy(msg = (m.msg+"World"))
        using(sessionB){myTable.insert(newMsg)}
        println("Inserted "+newMsg)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I apologize for the lack of documentation.  The using() construct is a new feature that is only available in SNAPSHOT builds.  I actually talked to Max about some of the documentation issues for early adopters yesterday and we are working to fix them.

There isn't a way that I can think of to bind a specific Session to a Query.  Looking at your example, it looks like an easy work around would be to invert your transactions.  When you create a query, Squeryl doesn't actually access the DB, it just creates an AST representing the SQL to be performed, so you don't need to issue your using(sessionA) at that point.  Then, when you are ready to iterate over the results you can wrap the query invocation in a using(sessionA) nested within your using(sessionB).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Dave, thanks for all your efforts on Squeryl, which has transformed how I regard ORM and firmed my commitment to Scala.  I'm surprised that using() should only be in snapshot, since I'm sure I just pulled the jar off the website.  Have updated my question with your solution which really clarified things.